# Generating permutations of the input sequence using backtracking

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

I am practicing for interviews on Leetcode and one of the questions is:

Given an array of numbers, you need to generate all the possible permutations.  For better understanding, I turned to the solutions, one of which is like this:

```
public class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
       List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
       // Arrays.sort(nums); // not necessary
       backtrack(list, new ArrayList<>(), nums);
       return list;
    }

    private void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> tempList, int [] nums){
       if(tempList.size() == nums.length){
          list.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
       } else{
          for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){ 
             if(tempList.contains(nums[i])) 
                 continue;
             System.out.println("Adding: "+nums[i]);
             tempList.add(nums[i]);
             backtrack(list, tempList, nums);
             System.out.println("Removing: "+nums[i]);
             tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);
          }
       }
    } 
}
```

The two `print` statements show me how the numbers are added and removed (and consequently the permutations generated):

> Adding: 1 
>   Adding: 2
>   Adding: 3
>   Removing: 3
>   Removing: 2
>   --------> why is `1` not removed here?
>   Adding: 3
>  
>   Adding: 2
>   Removing: 2
>   Removing: 3
>   Removing: 1
>   Adding: 2
>   Adding: 1
>   Adding: 3
>   Removing: 3
>   Removing: 1
>   Adding: 3
>   Adding: 1
>   Removing: 1
>   Removing: 3
>   Removing: 2
>   Adding: 3
>   Adding: 1
>   Adding: 2
>   Removing: 2
>   Removing: 1
>   Adding: 2
>   Adding: 1
>   Removing: 1
>   Removing: 2
>   Removing: 3

While I understood *how* it is adding and removing the numbers, I'm not sure *why* it is working that way.  As per my understanding, after generating the first permutation `<1,2,3>`, all these three numbers should be removed.  But that is not the case.  Only `<2,3>` are removed, leaving `1` behind.  Why is it so?  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: [Does the output make more sense if I add some spaces?](http://ideone.com/o7b5WY)

Comment: @Dukeling, yes, this is wonderful. :)  I got a bit of it. But it would be very helpful if I understand how _the code_ does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal processing - add next number until we hit the limit.

> Adding: 1
>
> Adding: 2
>
> Adding: 3

We hit the ceiling, record the `1,2,3` perm and back-track, removing`3`

> Removing: 3

We exit the `backtrack(3)` call and, as we just added `2` we immediately remove it.

> Removing: 2

We now **continue the loop that added `2` and try `3`** in the **second** position.

> Adding: 3

The list now contains `1,3`.

We now loop for the third entry and find that `2` is not in the list yet.

> Adding: 2

It will add `1,3,2` to the result list.

The balanced removal of `2`.

> Removing: 2

etc.

Comment: Got your point.  Thank you.  Sometimes this recursion makes my head spin! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems has problem, as after addition of 1,2,3 in list and you are backtracking twice only as per recursion so 1 will always be part of your list.

```
In Backtracking,
1
1->2
1->2->3
Remove 3 as no further element
Remove 2 from temp list but after this permute 2,3 ->3,2 
There is no need to remove all elements in single iteration over all elements, 
you can try with 4 input [1,2,3,4], will be more clear as many permutations will be 
there after removal of 2 as 2->3->4, 2->4->3.
```

Please find below alternate solution

```
public static void permutate() {
    int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    backTrack(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
}

public static void backTrack(int[] str, int l, int r) {
   if (l == r) {
    System.out.print("\n");
    for (int ele : str) {
     System.out.print(ele);
    }
    } else {
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            str = swap(str, l, i);
            backTrack(str, l + 1, r);
            str = swap(str, l, i);
        }
    }
}

public static int[] swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
 int temp = a[i];
 a[i] = a[j];
 a[j] = temp;
 return a;
}
```

If needed you can collect all permutation is any of the collection for further use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll tried to explain this

```
private void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> tempList, int [] nums){
   if(tempList.size() == nums.length){
      list.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
   } else{
      for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){ 
         if(tempList.contains(nums[i])) 
             continue;
         System.out.println("Adding: "+nums[i]);
         tempList.add(nums[i]);
         backtrack(list, tempList, nums);
         System.out.println("Removing: "+nums[i]);
         tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);
      }
   }
}
```

You start your backTracking, for each tab it's different recursion level, and each level has your own local variables (in this case 'i')

```
backtracking([empty list],[],[1,2,3])
   start for i = 0
   add to temp list nums[0] = 1
   call backtracking
   backtracking([],[1],[1,2,3])
      start for i = 0 // the other for it's waiting
      if(tempList.contains(nums[i])) //its true, then not add nums[0]
      now for i = 1
      add to temp list nums[1] = 2
      call backtracking
      backtracking([],[1,2],[1,2,3])
          start for i = 0 // the other two 'for' waiting
          if(tempList.contains(nums[i]))// true for nums[0],nums[1]
          now for i = 2
          add to temp list nums[2] = 3
          call backtracking
          backtracking([],[1,2,3],[1,2,3])
              if(tempList.size() == nums.length)//it's true
              //we have one permutation [1,2,3]
              //add templist in list
              finish this level of recursion, return to last level
          now for i = 3 then end recursion and remove
          tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);//after this templist = [1,2]
      now here the important part!!
      here remove again
      tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1); // after this templist = [1]

      now i = 2 //see in this level before i = 1
      then the for continue
      add to temp list nums[2] = 3
      tempList = [1,3]//see that you first add 3 before delete 1
      call backtracking
      backtracking([],[1,3],[1,2,3])
          repeat process...
          here only we can add nums[1]
          add to temp list nums[1] = 2
          tempList = [1,3,2]
          call backtracking
          backtracking([],[1,3,2],[1,2,3])
              if(tempList.size() == nums.length)//it's true
              //we have other permutation [1,3,2]
              finish this level of recursion, return to last level
          i = 3 then end and delete '2' number
      i = 3 then end and delete '3' number
   now i = 2 // see this is the first recursion and templist = []
   add to temp list nums[1] = 2
   call backtracking
      backtracking([],[2,],[1,2,3]) // and you can continues the recursion.
```

I recommend use debug in netbeans or eclipse, You can see each level of recursion and see how it works.